# How to print/catch all html element using html2pdf in a large document?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, html2pdf

I am using **html2pdf** library via [cdn](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.9.2/html2pdf.bundle.min.js) and follow their docs. I am just wondering whenever I convert my html into printable pdf but as it gets add element it is not rendered on canvas. The result is just like the image below:

[image: PDF generated from html]

I am using VanillaJS in my project.

**EDIT**

This is how I made my conversion and as per docs:

```
let pdfGenerator = document.querySelector('#pdfgenerator')
if (pdfGenerator) {
  pdfGenerator.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const employees = document.querySelector('#employees-division')
    //console.log(employees)
    //console.log(window)
    let opt = {
      //margin: 0.5,
      filename: 'Report.pdf',
      image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
      html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
      jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' },
    }
    
    html2pdf().from(employees).set(opt).save()

  })
}
```

and this is my code that displays my data:

```
function displayData(object, cat) {
  let container = document.querySelector('#employees-division')

  let category = document.querySelector('.'+cat)
  if (!category) {
    category = document.createElement('div')
    category.className = cat
    category.id = 'card-stats'

    container.appendChild(category)
  }

  let catTextRow = document.querySelector('#'+cat)
  if(!catTextRow) {
    catTextRow = document.createElement('div')
    catTextRow.className = 'row'
    catTextRow.id = cat
    
    let catTextCol = document.createElement('div')
    catTextCol.className = 'col s12 custom-category-header'//gradient-45deg-orange-deep-orange gradient-45deg-light-blue-teal, gradient-45deg-indigo-light-blue
    
    let catTextH4 = document.createElement('h4')
    catTextH4.className = 'center-align'
    catTextH4.innerHTML = cat.toUpperCase();
    
    catTextCol.appendChild(catTextH4)
    catTextRow.appendChild(catTextCol)
    category.appendChild(catTextRow)
  }
 //other elements that responsibles for displaying data
...
}
```

thus my html has these structures:

```
<div class="container" id="employees-division">
    <div class="administrative" id="card-stats">
        <div class="row" id="administrative">
            <div class="col s12 custom-category-header">
                <h4 class="center-align">ADMINISTRATIVE</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="admin-row">
           <div class="s12 m6 l4" id="admin-AANDD">
               <div id="administrative-AANDD">
                   <h5>A&D-ADMISSION DIVISION</h5>
               </div>
               <div class="cust-collapsible gradient-45deg-red-pink" id="AANDD0002">
                   <!-- Other Element and Data were displayed here -->
               </div>
               <div class="cust-collapsible gradient-45deg-red-pink" id="AANDD0003">
                   <!-- Other Element and Data were displayed here -->
               </div>
               ....
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?**

Comment: Please provide some example code for people to reproduce the issue, and ideally, some code that could run in a repl online or that could be easily pulled down from a public github or other hosting solution.

Comment: I already updated my question. I am guessing, maybe because **html2pdf** can not handle large data? I convert all my webpage (all data shown on my webpage which is more than two thousand records) into pdf but the result was all blank.

Comment: Could you show us the bit where you add element(s)?

Comment: @AHaworth my elements were displayed into my html via Javascript's ```createElement``` as shown on my function ```displayData(object, cat)```. I could not find any solution for it why it isn't captured on my pdf.

Comment: Just to clarify in your question: does "but as it gets add element it is not rendered on canvas" mean that the elements you are adding programmatically are not rendering in the pdf?  If so, when is the PDF generation triggered?  You've provided some snippets, but I'm worried there still isn't a complete picture in the question in terms of 1) expected output 2) complete code